# Phonegap/Cordova ios error on Ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: ios, ubuntu, cordova

Both the commands `phonegap run ios` and `cordova platform add ios` throw a similar error

```
Error: An error occured during creation of ios sub-project. 
~/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.3.0/bin/create: 33: 
~/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.3.0/bin/create: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Phonegap/cordova version is 3.3.0.

Android works fine.

Any idea for a fix?

Answer (score 3):

You can't run iOS on ubuntu, just on mac osx

to add iOS to the project try with `phonegap build iOS`

That should add the iOS part to phonegap build if you have your phonegap build account properly set